# MySQL Update SET with CASE statements

Tags: mysql

I've been working on a hierarchy tree using left and right ids. So my database has `parent_id`, `left_id` and `right_id` columns, amongst others.

I built a number of tests with PHPUnit using an sqlite, :memory: database, which all work as expected. However, now that I've come to use the queries in a MySQL database, it's behaving in an unexpected manner.

Given a simplified test database with a `roles` table like:

```
        id   parent_id   left_id   right_id
Node1    1        null         1          8
Node2    2           1         2          7
Node3    3           2         3          4
Node4    4           2         5          6
```

A working, full query to move Node3 after Node4 in the tree in sqlite tests is:

```
UPDATE `roles` SET 
`left_id` = (CASE 
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` >= 3 AND `roles`.`right_id` <= 4) THEN (`left_id` + 2)
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` > 3 AND `roles`.`right_id` <= 6) THEN (`left_id` - 2)
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` <= 5 AND `roles`.`right_id` >= 6) THEN (`left_id` - 2)
    ELSE `left_id` END), 
`right_id` = (CASE
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` >= 3 AND `roles`.`right_id` <= 4) THEN (`right_id` + 2)
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` > 3 AND `roles`.`right_id` <= 6) THEN (`right_id` - 2)
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` < 3 AND `roles`.`right_id` > 4) THEN (`right_id` - 2)
    ELSE `right_id` END),
`parent_id` = (CASE
    WHEN `roles`.`id` = 3 THEN 2
    ELSE `parent_id` END),
`depth` = (CASE 
    WHEN (`roles`.`left_id` >= 3 AND `roles`.`right_id` <= 4) THEN (depth + 0)
    ELSE `depth` END),
`updated_at` = '2016-12-07 15:50:17'
WHERE (left_id BETWEEN 3 AND 6 OR right_id BETWEEN 3 AND 6)
```

However, I'm finding that running the same query through a MySQL database (and through Sequel Pro), the `right_id` of Node4 isn't being updated to `4` as it should be, and is staying as `6`.

Interestingly, if I remove the the `left_id` section entirely from the query and don't change it in any other way, the `right_id` columns do update correctly (Node3 `right_id` becomes `6`, Node4 `right_id` becomes `4`).

Any ideas as to why that might be the case?

Comment: I don't have time to examine your query in depth; but is your UPDATE logic taking into account that the CASE used to set the right_id, will be using the new left_id value, and the CASE for setting depth will be using the new left_id and right_id values?

Comment: Uh, no. They do not. I'll be honest, I'd never come across that as a thing, and given that it works as I had expected in sqlite, I hadn't even considered that columns are updated in sequence... I guess I've got a lot of code revisions to do.

Comment: Yep. Similarly, as most my experience has been in MySQL, it was a little surprise when I transitioned to MSSQL that its UPDATEs use the "old" values throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the SET clause of an UPDATE statement uses the most "current"(even within the statement itself) values of the fields referenced.

For example, lets say you have a row `(f1, f2, f3)` with values `(1, 2, 3)`, and want to "rotate" the fields' values. You cannot do something like `UPDATE ... SET f1 = f2, f2 = f3, f3 = f1 ...` as your final state would be `(2, 3, 2)`. Instead, you can do something like `...SET @i = f1, f1 = f2, f2 = f3, f3 = @i ...` *(if my recollection that you can assign to session variables in an UPDATE isn't flawed.)*

This example may not be helpful in your particular case, but is intended to demonstrate the general behavior.